# CSS select first child only if two children

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any way to select the first child only if there is a second child? I'd like to hide the first `<p></p>` tag only if there is a second one. Is there any way to do this with CSS?

My code is this

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <p>something</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if there is a third or fourth child?

Answer (score 25):

You can only do this by combining `:first-child` and `:nth-last-child()`, which means in pure CSS you won't get any better support than IE9 and later:

```
p:first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

If you're looking to hide the first `p` when it has siblings at all (i.e. it doesn't matter whether there are 2, 3, 4... children in total), use this instead:

```
p:first-child:not(:only-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: IE8 will support `first-child` if there is a `DOCTYPE`

Comment: @asmies: But not `:nth-last-child()`.

Comment: Why do you need it? He only needs to hide the first one. **Edit**: My bad, I overlooked the "only if there is a second child"

Comment: Elegant! I didn't know you can chain these.

Answer (score 1):

Does the solution need to be cross-browser compatible? If so, I'm not sure if it can be done with CSS. However, it's easy to accomplish with jQuery:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SVTxD/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.myDiv').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).children().length);
        if ($(this).children('p').length > 1){
            $(this).children('p').first().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively (thank you BoltClock):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.myDiv p:first-child:nth-last-child(2)').hide();
});
```

If jQuery isn't an option (or it doesn't need to work in older browsers), then Josh C's answer is correct.

EDIT: Includedd @BoltClock's suggestion as an alternative.

Comment: With a sufficiently recent version of jQuery you can just throw in `p:first-child:nth-last-child(2)` and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, added your syntax as an alternative.